# Как динамически менять названия методов в компонентах в Vue

Tags: vue.js

Есть 2 динамических раздела Question и Answer, у каждого из этих двух разделов есть  компонент question/test.vue и answer/test.vue и они полностью одинаковые кроме названия метода у question/test.vue есть метод changeQuestion() а у answer/test.vue есть метод changeAnswer(). Я бы хотел вынести test.vue в глобальные компоненты но как можно решить проблему с разными названием методов?

answer/test.vue

```
<template>some code</template>
<script>
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
    name: 'Test',

    methods: {
        ...mapActions(['changeAnswer']),

        onChange(state) {
            this.changeAnswer();
        },

        pageChange() {...}
    },
};
</script>
```

question/test.vue

```
<template>some code</template>
<script>
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
    name: 'Test',

    methods: {
        ...mapActions(['changeQuestion']),

        onChange(state) {
            this.changeQuestion();
        },

        pageChange() {...}
    },
};
</script>
```

Comment: объеденить методы в один и вынести его в миксин, который потом подключить к каждому из компонентов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю здесь достаточно добавить свойство компонента (props).

Для примера создадим новый компонент: `test/test.vue`

```
<template>some code</template>
<script>
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
    name: 'Test',
    props: {
        action: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapActions([this.action]),
        
        onChange(state) {
            this[this.action]();
        },

        pageChange() {...}
    },
};
</script>
```

Использовать можно так:

```
<test action="changeQuestion"/>
```

Подробнее можно почитать на [странице официальной документации](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#ad)